# javascript for drawing network diagram for project management tasks

Tags: javascript, flash

im developing a web based project management web site using php
i need charts for tasks
about the gant chart it is ok i found a javascript library which functions can take the tasks names , dates and durations then draw a gant chart.
but my problem is about network diagram for the tasks , i need javascripts libraries or flash action script can make this.

Answer (score 5):

not used this myself yet, but have you checked out [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) ?

Comment: ok that is good , but i need to generate graph 
i mean functions that takes tasks duration as parameters and generate the graph
thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

flot.js is probably not the best solution for generating network diagrams, but it is nice for traditional x/y coordinate diagrams.  To others who might land here during a search, check it out:  [flot.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)

You might also look at [JSGannt](http://www.jsgantt.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ext Gantt, might be what you're looking for..?

http://www.ext-scheduler.com/gantt.html